# Running the same MYSQL query for time periods throughout the day, is there a better way?

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

I am generating a report for my directors. It is an hourly breakdown of the calls and agents that are logged into our dialler system so we can see the performance throughout the day. As the day goes on there are more and more queries and more and more results making it very slow.

Is there a better way to do this than calling the same query with different parameters?

One of the columns is indexed and I am only selecting that.

Would `COUNT()` be faster than counting rows using `num_rows`?

I am just not sure what is the best practice to stop me hammering this database and also improve performance.

So this is a snippet of it but I am also running another 30 similar queries pulling different results from different tables. It just takes a while to load. Would you be better off selecting everything for the day then formatting the data up with PHP? I am not sure what the best way to do this is. In the query's below I am selecting `*` but I have since changed that to just pull the indexed column but it doesn't seem to make much difference.

```
$Callssql9to11 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '09:00:00') AND TIME ('11:00:00')";
    $Callssql9to11result = $conn->query($Callssql9to11);
    /////////////////11-12///////////////////////////
    $Callssql11to12 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '11:00:00') AND TIME ('12:00:00')";
    $Callssql11to12result = $conn->query($Callssql11to12);
    /////////////////12-13///////////////////////////
    $Callssql12to13 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '12:00:00') AND TIME ('13:00:00')";
    $Callssql12to13result = $conn->query($Callssql12to13);
    /////////////////13-14///////////////////////////
    $Callssql13to14 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '13:00:00') AND TIME ('14:00:00')";
    $Callssql13to14result = $conn->query($Callssql13to14);
    /////////////////14-15///////////////////////////
    $Callssql14to15 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '14:00:00') AND TIME ('15:00:00')";
    $Callssql14to15result = $conn->query($Callssql14to15);
    /////////////////15-16///////////////////////////
    $Callssql15to16 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '15:00:00') AND TIME ('16:00:00')";
    $Callssql15to16result = $conn->query($Callssql15to16);
    /////////////////16-17///////////////////////////
    $Callssql16to17 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '16:00:00') AND TIME ('17:00:00')";
    $Callssql16to17result = $conn->query($Callssql16to17);
    /////////////////17-18///////////////////////////
    $Callssql17to18 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '17:00:00') AND TIME ('18:00:00')";
    $Callssql17to18result = $conn->query($Callssql17to18);
    /////////////////18-20///////////////////////////
    $Callssql18to20 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '19:00:00') AND TIME ('20:00:00')";
    $Callssql18to20result = $conn->query($Callssql18to20);
    /////////////////ALL///////////////////////////
    $CallssqlALL = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date` BETWEEN (TIME '09:00:00') AND TIME ('20:00:00')";
    $CallssqlALLresult = $conn->query($CallssqlALL);


///////////////////9-11///////////////////////////
    $Connectssql9to11 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today`WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date`BETWEEN (TIME '09:00:00') AND TIME ('11:00:00') AND `status` IN (SELECT (STATUS) FROM `status_combined`WHERE `human_answered`='Y')";
    $Connectssql9to11result = $conn->query($Connectssql9to11);


$Leadssql9to11 = "SELECT * FROM `outbound_log_today`WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date`BETWEEN (TIME '09:00:00') AND TIME ('11:00:00')
                        AND `status`='passed'";
    $Leadssql9to11result = $conn->query($Leadssql9to11);



$Agentssql9to11 = "SELECT DISTINCT USER FROM `outbound_log_today`WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
                        AND `call_date`BETWEEN (TIME '09:00:00') AND TIME ('11:00:00') AND `user` NOT IN ('VDAD')";
    $Agentssql9to11result = $conn->query($Agentssql9to11);

/////////////////// html //////////////////////////
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th scope="col">9 - 11</th>
        <th scope="col">11 - 12</th>
        <th scope="col">12 - 13</th>
        <th scope="col">13 - 14</th>
        <th scope="col">14 - 15</th>
        <th scope="col">15 - 16</th>
        <th scope="col">16 - 17</th>
        <th scope="col">17 - 18</th>
        <th scope="col">18 - 19</th>
        <th scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Calls</th>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql9to11result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql11to12result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql12to13result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql13to14result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql14to15result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql15to16result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql16to17result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql17to18result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Callssql18to20result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $CallssqlALLresult->num_rows; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Connect%</th>
        <td><?php if($Callssql9to11result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql9to11result->num_rows / $Callssql9to11result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql11to12result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectsql11to12result->num_rows / $Callssql11to12result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql12to13result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql12to13result->num_rows / $Callssql12to13result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql13to14result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql13to14result->num_rows / $Callssql13to14result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql14to15result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql14to15result->num_rows / $Callssql14to15result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql15to16result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql15to16result->num_rows / $Callssql15to16result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql16to17result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql16to17result->num_rows / $Callssql16to17result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql17to18result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql17to18result->num_rows / $Callssql17to18result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql18to20result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql18to20result->num_rows / $Callssql18to20result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($CallssqlALLresult->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($ConnectssqlALLresult->num_rows / $CallssqlALLresult->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Connect</th>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql9to11result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectsql11to12result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql12to13result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql13to14result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql14to15result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql15to16result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql16to17result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql17to18result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Connectssql18to20result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ConnectssqlALLresult->num_rows; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Conv%</th>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql9to11result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql9to11result->num_rows / $Connectssql9to11result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadsql11to12result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadsql11to12result->num_rows / $Connectsql11to12result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql12to13result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql12to13result->num_rows / $Connectssql12to13result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql13to14result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql13to14result->num_rows / $Connectssql13to14result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql14to15result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql14to15result->num_rows / $Connectssql14to15result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql15to16result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql15to16result->num_rows / $Connectssql15to16result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql16to17result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql16to17result->num_rows / $Connectssql16to17result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql17to18result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql17to18result->num_rows / $Connectssql17to18result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql18to20result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql18to20result->num_rows / $Connectssql18to20result->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
        <td><?php if($LeadssqlALLresult->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($LeadssqlALLresult->num_rows / $ConnectssqlALLresult->num_rows * 100, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?>%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Leads</th>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql9to11result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadsql11to12result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql12to13result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql13to14result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql14to15result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql15to16result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql16to17result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql17to18result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Leadssql18to20result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $LeadssqlALLresult->num_rows; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Active Agents</th>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql9to11result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentsql11to12result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql12to13result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql13to14result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql14to15result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql15to16result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql16to17result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql17to18result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Agentssql18to20result->num_rows; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $totalAgents; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Calls Per Agent</th>
        <td><?php if($Callssql9to11result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql9to11result->num_rows / $Agentssql9to11result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql11to12result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql11to12result->num_rows / $Agentsql11to12result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql12to13result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql12to13result->num_rows / $Agentssql12to13result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql13to14result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql13to14result->num_rows / $Agentssql13to14result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql14to15result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql14to15result->num_rows / $Agentssql14to15result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql15to16result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql15to16result->num_rows / $Agentssql15to16result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql16to17result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql16to17result->num_rows / $Agentssql16to17result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql17to18result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql17to18result->num_rows / $Agentssql17to18result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Callssql18to20result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Callssql18to20result->num_rows / $Agentssql18to20result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($CallssqlALLresult->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($CallssqlALLresult->num_rows / $totalAgents, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Connects Per Agent</th>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql9to11result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql9to11result->num_rows / $Agentssql9to11result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectsql11to12result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectsql11to12result->num_rows / $Agentsql11to12result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql12to13result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql12to13result->num_rows / $Agentssql12to13result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql13to14result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql13to14result->num_rows / $Agentssql13to14result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql14to15result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql14to15result->num_rows / $Agentssql14to15result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql15to16result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql15to16result->num_rows / $Agentssql15to16result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql16to17result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql16to17result->num_rows / $Agentssql16to17result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql17to18result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql17to18result->num_rows / $Agentssql17to18result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Connectssql18to20result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Connectssql18to20result->num_rows / $Agentssql18to20result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($ConnectssqlALLresult->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($ConnectssqlALLresult->num_rows / $totalAgents, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Leads Per Agent</th>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql9to11result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql9to11result->num_rows / $Agentssql9to11result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadsql11to12result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadsql11to12result->num_rows / $Agentsql11to12result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql12to13result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql12to13result->num_rows / $Agentssql12to13result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql13to14result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql13to14result->num_rows / $Agentssql13to14result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql14to15result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql14to15result->num_rows / $Agentssql14to15result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql15to16result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql15to16result->num_rows / $Agentssql15to16result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql16to17result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql16to17result->num_rows / $Agentssql16to17result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql17to18result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql17to18result->num_rows / $Agentssql17to18result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($Leadssql18to20result->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($Leadssql18to20result->num_rows / $Agentssql18to20result->num_rows, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if($LeadssqlALLresult->num_rows!=0){echo number_format($LeadssqlALLresult->num_rows / $totalAgents, 2);}else{echo "0";} ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>





    9 - 11  11 - 12 12 - 13 13 - 14 14 - 15 15 - 16 16 - 17 17 - 18 18 - 19 Total
Calls   2677    6444    5865    72  0   0   0   0   0   15057
Connect%    5.83%   3.26%   2.59%   8.33%   0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  3.48%
Connect 156 210 152 6   0   0   0   0   0   524
Conv%   11.54%  9.05%   8.55%   0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  9.54%
Leads   18  19  13  0   0   0   0   0   0   50
Active Agents   19  25  22  7   0   0   0   0   0   18.25
Calls Per Agent 140.89  257.76  266.59  10.29   0   0   0   0   0   825.04
Connects Per Agent  8.21    8.40    6.91    0.86    0   0   0   0   0   28.71
Leads Per Agent 0.95    0.76    0.59    0   0   0   0   0   0   2.74
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to get to with this sql you have pasted here. Surely this can be done in a single statement with a `CASE` expression or `If()` function and you would do your aggregating there as well, but it's difficult to understand what your output is supposed to look like from just the SQL.

Comment: So I have updated the question to reflect that. It includes the HTML table. So the table would have a columns displaying the breakdown of hours throughout the day. Then each row displays a statistic eg, calls placed, conversion rates etc. So it displays all of the data throughout that day hour by hour breakdown. Rough idea of what the table generates included in the question.

Comment: Cool. I see that now. Can you share just one of your `ConnectssqlMondayALLresult` and `LeadssqlMondayALLresult` and `AgentssqlThursdayALLresult` and anything else I may be not seeing SQL (You don't have to share for each break down in time or day, just so we can see the tables/sql being used). I suspect all of this can be done in a single SQL statement (or maybe like 4 tops).

Comment: Sorry for that I will post them to the question now for you :) Thank you and sorry about getting back to you I am actually at work at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to run a query for each hour

```
SELECT call_date, COUNT(call_date) FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
GROUP BY call_date`
```

if i get correctly your table structure this query will give you the number of rows for each call_date. It works if you round each call_date to the hour where it happens and not to the exact timestamp

If you have the timestamp you can do:

```
SELECT HOUR(call_date), COUNT(call_date) FROM `outbound_log_today` WHERE `campaign_id`='003'
GROUP BY HOUR(call_date)`
```

HOUR() will extract the hour part from the time you have. I.e. if you have 09:03:00 it will give you 09.

Every time you will run this query you will get the count of how many rows you have for each hour you run the query in. Each time you load the page the table will be filled with updated values. Then, based on the call date column, you can fill each cell accordingly.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you ever so much. I can't believe it can be done that simply. Thanks ever so much for your help.